# Angular 7 - Material component CSS not loading

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I am working on a new Angular 7 project and trying to use the out of the box material components.

Some of the css is not being applied and i cannot seem to discover why.

For example, I have an  declared as matInput, but the styling is not applied and it still looks like a basic HTML input, but the styling for other things such as the cards is being applied.

[image]

Here is my angular.json:
[image]

styles.scss
[image]

Input field:
[image]

Is there a stylesheet im missing or something I forgot? 
Why is my matInput not being formatted?

Comment: wrap the input tag with <mat-form-field>

Comment: import the matinputmodule to ur module where this component is declared

Comment: @Y_Moshe Thank you. I have used that before, but didnt realize that specific tag was the one that applied the CSS formatting. I thought it was the `matInput` flag that applied it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how i have declared one in the past hopefully it will help:

```
<form (submit)="onSaveProject(projectForm, projectForm.value)" #projectForm="ngForm" *ngIf="!isloading">
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" name="projectDescirption" 
  [ngModel]="project?.projectDescirption"
  required
  minlength="5"
  placeholder="Project Description"
  #projectDescirption="ngModel">
  <mat-error *ngIf="projectDescirption.invalid">Please descibe the project (minimum 5 characters)</mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Also ensure you have the module imported, again here is an example of how i have done it in the past:

**app.moudle.ts**

```
import { 
 MatInputModule,
 MatCardModule,
 MatButtonModule,
 MatFormFieldModule,
 MatToolbarModule,
 MatExpansionModule,
 MatProgressSpinnerModule,
 MatPaginatorModule,
 MatDialogModule,
 MatOptionModule,
 MatSelectModule,
 MatDividerModule,
 MatCheckboxModule,
 MatSlideToggleModule,
 MatProgressBarModule,
 MatDatepickerModule,
 MatNativeDateModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  MatInputModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatOptionModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule
]
})
```